# Constructing frequency table of Objects in ArrayList<Object[]>

Tags: java, algorithm, frequency

I try to implement [Incognito k-anonymization algorithm](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=2&ved=0CB8QFjAB&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwwwcs.uni-paderborn.de%2Fcs%2Fboettcher%2Flehre%2FSS05%2Fsem-ss05%2Fincognito.pdf&rct=j&q=incognito%20algorithm%20java&ei=QuMqTdWkNIiYOor94IQD&usg=AFQjCNE6zunwPbBP4jkyu2jlSOLyAy2dUw&sig2=JSXIQsC6vqCmMoJP8-X3Ig&cad=rja) in Java. 
A part of this algorithm is the frequency set construction for a given table. The columns of the table vary each time so I decided to represent the table as an ArrayList of Object[] where Object[] size is the number of the columns. In this Object I store each row's values for each columns.

I try to construct the frequency table using the following method:

```
ArrayList<Object[]> table = new ArrayList<Object[]>();
....// table filling//.....
ArrayList<Object[]> frequencySet = new ArrayList<Object[]>();
for(int i=0;i<table.size();i++)
     {
         Integer count = 1;
         int j = 0;
         for(j=i+1;j<table.size();j++)
         {
             if(Arrays.equals(table.get(i), table.get(j)))
             {
                 //System.out.println(i+" equals to "+j);
                 count++;
                 table.remove(j);
                 j = j-1;
             }
         }
         int size = arguments.size()+1;
         Object[] anObject = new Object[size];
         System.arraycopy(table.get(i), 0, anObject, 0, arguments.size());
         anObject[size-1] = count;
         frequencySet.add(anObject);
     }
```

The problem is that the algorithm is very slow, and I figured out that the most of the time is consumed in this method. (For 100.000 data it needs 13min to run- I don't know if this is normal). Is there a faster way to construct frequency table?

Comment: If you have the column number as the last element, every column will be different and you can just take a deep copy of the columns.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Never use `remove` on an `ArrayList`, it's O(size()). Also, your count variable gets wrapped and unwrapped each time you increment it. Make its type `int` and wrap it into `Integer` only at the very end.

Without knowing anything about the type of Objects you store, I assume the methods `equals` and `hashCode` are redefined for them. Then the best thing that comes into mind is wrap the array of Object's into a class Row (it's a good thing to do anyway), redefine equals and hashCode for Row (using Arrays.equals and Arrays.hashCode) and count the occurrences of each Row in one pass using a

```
HashMap<Row, Integer> count;
```

```
for (Row row : table) {
    if (count.containsKey(row)) {
        count.put(row, count.get(row) + 1);
    } else {
        count.put(row, 1);
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 - but it is probably worth having the `Row.hashCode()` method cache the hashcode value it calculates.

Answer (score 1):

Sort them, and then count reoccurances with a loop after that. That will bring it down to O(n log n)

or use a hashtable to do your counting instead. That should be a linear time calculation.